# Облицовка форм

Tags: css

Хороший css код красивой облицовки текстового поля и кнопки ?

Comment: Вам нужно оформить красиво текст и создать кнопку с помощью CSS? 
Конкретнее можно вопрос поставить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
border-style: double; /* Стиль рамки */
border-color: #FACE8D; /* Цвет границы */
border-width: 3px 7px 7px 4px; /* Толщина границы */
```

Стили посмотреть можно тут:
[image: Стили]
А вообще читайте [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css).

Если хочется совсем необычную рамку, подойдёт такой вариант:

```
-moz-border-image: url(images/bg-image.png) 30 round round;
-webkit-border-image: url(images/bg-image.png) 30 round round; 
-o-border-image: url(images/bg-image.png) 30 round round;
border-image: url(images/bg-image.png) 30 round round;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот посмотрите - здесь то, что вам надо: http://uniformjs.com/.